# How to console axios result inside useEffect in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and I am using `nextjs`.
Right now I am using Axios to fetch data via API but am unable to display on the page, For this, I am trying to console.log inside `useEffect` but nothing is displaying, How can I use console.log and display data in my page? Here is my current code

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React, { FormEventHandler, useRef } from "react";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import $ from "jquery";

const Test = () => {
  const [post, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const { data: res } = await axios.get(
        "https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/get_demodata/"
      );
      console.log("here is data" + res);
      setPosts(res);
    };
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {post.length > 0 ? (
            post.map((post: any, index: number) => (
              <tr key={post.id}>
                <td>{post.id}</td>
                <td>{post.title}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use try-catch block

You can try this code below:

```
const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/get_demodata/"
      );
      console.log("here is data", res);
      setPosts(res.data.blogs);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-rgb-m0zglq?file=/src/App.js:304-594

Comment: your code is working but nothing displaying in my console

Comment: dhiman and what if i am getting error ?

Comment: not getting anything in console

Comment: right now i cant see blogs in console.log